# Rails current_page? UrlGenerationError on View

Tags: html, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, view

I'm new to rails and what I'm trying to do is the following:

When a user clicks on a user profile page, the style of the background will change according to the user's preference. I'm using `current_page?` to identify if I am in the show page(user's profile).

Is there any better approach to handle this?

**application.html.erb**

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html class='no-js' lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title><%= full_title(yield(:title)) %></title>
    <!-- Link foundation stylesheet -->
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application" %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "vendor/modernizr" %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= render 'layouts/shim' %>
  </head>
  <body>
    <% if current_page?(controller: 'users', action: 'show') %>
      <div style="background-attachment: fixed;
       background-image: linear-gradient(<%= @user.first_bg_color %> 0%,
        <%= @user.second_bg_color %> 100%);">
    <% else %>
      <div style="background-attachment: fixed;
       background-image: linear-gradient(<%= current_user.first_bg_color %> 0%,
        <%= current_user.second_bg_color %> 100%);">
    <% end %>
        <%= render 'layouts/offcanvas_start' %>
        <%= yield %>
        <%= render 'layouts/offcanvas_end' %>
      </div>
    <%= debug(params) if Rails.env.development? %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
  </body>
  </html>
```

I'm getting this error when I'm going e.i. root_path
>

> No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"users"}
>
> app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:14:in _app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__2507795966534755030_70012866854080'

Answer (score 0):

Neil,

Try the following:

```
current_page?(url_for(:controller => 'users', :action => 'show'))
```